# react router 4 - how to make a root path with nested routes but fallback to not-found

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I just found a possible acceptable solution to my problem after struggling for hours with it and even started to write this post, but I still want to know if there is a better way to do what I want to do.

I want to have a main App component that is as basic as possible that wraps the entire application. Then I want to have a login route with some sub-routes, a main-application route with all the application routes and a not found page. The idea is that the main-application route (named Home from now) should contain the layout of the application and such layout should not re-render from one sub-route to another.

My objective is a route configuration like this:

```js
{
    path: "/",
    component: App,
    childRoutes: [
        {
            path: "login",
            childRoutes: [
                {
                    path: "",
                    name: "login"
                },
                {
                    path: "signup",
                    name: "Sign up"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            path: "/",
            name: "Home",
            component: Layout,
            childRoutes: [
                {
                    path: "",
                    name: "Default page",
                },
                {
                    path: "stats",
                    name: "Statistics"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            path: "*",
            name: "Page not found"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, because the Home route does not have an exact match attached to it it will never allow the not found page to be rendered. That is the reason why the login route is before this one.
If I add the `exact=true` requirement to the Home path, then none of the sub-routes will match which is an even worse problem.
The only solution that I found so far (and I don't even know how good it is) is to rename the '*' path to 'not-found', put it in front of the Home route and add a redirect to not-found as an ultimate fallback on every collection of routes.

This is how every nested route looks like:

```js
    <Switch>
      {children}
      <Redirect to="/not-found" />
    </Switch>)
```

One important thing to note is that I have more than one switch, which is probably related to my routing problem. This is an overview of how it looks when it matches `/stats`:

[image: router-structure]

I'm using a rekit boilerplate and routes are generated from Objects and each child route has it's own switch.

Answer (score 0):

So I wrapped all my JSON defined routes on a switch statement, with a redirect at the end of the switch. Then the not-found is the first route. Then, if no route matches, it will redirect you to the not found

```
  // Use Switch so that only the first matched route is rendered.
  return (
    <Switch>
      {children}
      <Redirect to="/not-found" />
    </Switch>
  );
```

Then the route config looks like this

```
[
    {
        "path": "/",
        "name": "root",
        "childRoutes": [
            {
                "path": "not-found",
                "name": "Page not found"
            },
            {
                "path": "login",
                "name": "Login",
                "component": TheComponent
                "childRoutes": [
                    {
                        "path": "signup",
                        "name": "Sign up",
                        "component": TheComponent
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "path": "/",
                "name": "Home",
                "component": {
                    "compare": null,
                    "displayName": "Connect(DefaultPage)"
                },
                "childRoutes": [
                    {
                        "path": "",
                        "name": "Default page",
                        "isIndex": true,
                        "exact": true,
                        "autoIndexRoute": true
                    },
                    {
                        "path": "timer",
                        "name": "Default page",
                        "isIndex": true
                    },
                    {
                        "path": "stats",
                        "name": "Stats"
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```